# SharpArch.Domain.PreconditionException: 'An ISessionStorage has not been configured'

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, asp.net-identity

I tried to build ASP.NET Identity project with hibernate 
SharpArch.Domain.PreconditionException: 'An ISessionStorage has not been configured'
https://github.com/Streamc/IdHiber

I borrow code from https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/tree/master/source/NHibernate.AspNet.Web project 
And I made new project and add some files.
I made Register.html and paste code in about .cshtml file

```
@model IdHiber.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

It shows error in:

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(NHibernateSession.Current)))
        {
        }
...
}
```

I keep a mysqlite DB. What can I do to

```
[PreconditionException: An ISessionStorage has not been configured]
   SharpArch.Domain.Check.Require(Boolean assertion, String message) in c:\projects\milesibastos\Sharp-Architecture\Solutions\SharpArch.Domain\DesignByContract\Check.cs:296
   SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.CurrentFor(String factoryKey) in c:\projects\milesibastos\Sharp-Architecture\Solutions\SharpArch.NHibernate\NHibernateSession.cs:117
   SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.get_Current() in c:\projects\milesibastos\Sharp-Architecture\Solutions\SharpArch.NHibernate\NHibernateSession.cs:80
   IdHiber.Controllers.AccountController..ctor() in C:\Users\userx\source\repos\IdHiber\IdHiber\Controllers\AccountController.cs:16

[TargetInvocationException: 
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +247
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'IdHiber.Controllers.AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +194
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

But I don't have the `c:\projects\milesibastos` folder!

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you got this issue sorted but I ran in to the same issue and resolved it by modifying my startup.cs to contain the following

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        ConfigureData();
    }

    private static void ConfigureData()
    {
        var storage = new WebSessionStorage(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance);
        DataConfig.Configure(storage);
    }
}
```

Also make sure you have a hibernate.cfg file in your bin folder. I hope this saves someone some time!

Comment: What is DataConfig? Is it from Mysql ? I Have SQL Server DB, What should I replace DataConfig with?